# How to transform a for loop into stream loop

Tags: loops, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How to transform this code into a stream loop:

```
for(long l = 1L; l <= 250000; l++) {
     v = value.add(BigInteger.valueOf(myMethod.getInt()));
}
```

I need to get the 'v' as a unique BigInteger value.

Comment: I just need to run myMethod.getInt() 25000 times. myMethod.getInt() return a random int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BigInteger result = IntStream.range(0, 25000)
  .map(i -> myMethod.getInt())
  .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
  .reduce(BigInteger.valueOf(0), BigInteger::add)
```

Another answer with `IntStream.generate(myMethod::getInt)` and `limit` is more elegant :)

Comment: With this code I was not able to get the final value of the sum. Like int value = IntStream.range(0, 25000)
  .map(i -> myMethod.getInt())
  .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
  .map(value::add)   and I got two errors: Error:(16, 96) java: incompatible types: long cannot be converted to java.math.BigDecimal
Error:(16, 79) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that java.util.stream.Stream<U> conforms to java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: @Roland if `value` collects the sum you can go with `.reduce(BigInteger.valueOf(0), BigInteger::add)`

Comment: I dont know whats its the problem but the result is coming with very similar values. I believe the code is not adding correctly

Comment: Instead of `BigInteger.valueOf(0)`, you can use `BigInteger.ZERO`. Alternative solution are `IntStream.generate(myMethod::getInt).limit(25000).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)  …` or `Stream.generate(() -> BigInteger.valueOf(myMethod.getInt())).limit(25000) …`.

Comment: @Ilya Zinkovich I preformed some tests and its correct. Thank you very much IIya.

Comment: I added the .parallel into the stream pipeline and this didn't affect the time to complete. Someone know why?

Comment: @Holger I came up with the same solution in parallel before reading your comments. Hope you don't think I stole your solution!

Comment: @Michael nope, I posted it as suggestion anyway, not as an answer. Besides that, finding such canonical solutions simultaneously, is not unusual.

Comment: @Roland a) wrong benchmark methodology b) whatever happens inside `myMethod.getInt()` (e.g. using a synchronized random generator). If all this method does, is returning a random int, how about `BigInteger result = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(25000, [min, max]) [.parallel()] .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf).reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add);`? Though, to sum up `25000` `int` values, you don’t need `BigInteger` anyway, as even the `long` value range is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally, it looks like your `myMethod.getInt` method is a generator. Therefore, the best way to do this, in my opinion, is to [create an infinite stream from your generator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#generate-java.util.function.IntSupplier-).

```
IntStream.generate(myMethod::getInt)
    .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
    .limit(25000)
    .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add)
```

This is clearer because you don't have to specify a range - the range is not what you care about, the number of elements is (i.e. the size of the range). You also don't have to ignore the parameter when you're mapping.